# 1-dimension Perlin Noise implementation in Clojure

Tags: clojure, perlin-noise

I'm searching for an implementation of 1-dimension perlin noise in Clojure, so far i find a 3-Dimension implementation:

https://github.com/indy/perlin/blob/master/src/perlin/core.clj

But it don't really fit my needs

There is also the one from Processing that was wrapped in quil:

https://github.com/quil/quil/blob/master/src/quil/core.clj#L2427

But i don't know how to extract it (it is binded to the current applet)

Comment: clisk may help you - https://github.com/mikera/clisk/blob/5eb65751a5cd13a9723e9cfbccd73da402b4239a/src/main/java/clisk/noise/Perlin.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a library called Clisk that may help you.

https://github.com/mikera/clisk

It has 1D, 2D, 3D and 4D noise generators of various sorts, including Perlin and Simplex noise.